# How to stop Redux flow when action is dispatched

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

So for every dispatched action in redux will call the render of every component And these components are compared to the previously displayed component. Any diff is identified and updated.

My question is, is there a way we can stop the calling of update(render) of unnecessary components?

Example
Component **A** is dispatching action which affects Component **B** & does not affect Component **C**.
In this case whenever action is dispatched every render method of every component is called. How to stop calling of Component C's render method here?

Comment: you can stop rendering of a component if you wish https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

Comment: component C will be re-rendered only if it use props that was updated by the dispatched action, otherwise not.

Answer (score 1):

If the part of the store you selected (in `mapStateToProps`) has not changed (using shallow compare `===`), then your component will not be re-rendered.

It's explicitely described in the [documentation](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate#return-values-determine-if-your-component-re-renders)

> React Redux internally implements the shouldComponentUpdate method such that the wrapper component re-renders precisely when the data your component needs has changed. By default, React Redux decides whether the contents of the object returned from mapStateToProps are different using === comparison (a "shallow equality" check) on each fields of the returned object. If any of the fields have changed, then your component will be re-rendered so it can receive the updated values as props.
>
> Note that returning a mutated object of the same reference is a common mistake that can result in your component not re-rendering when expected.